# Can I build a separate trap to drain my reverse osmosis system

Tags: plumbing

I have a single sink with disposal on an island counter.
The plumbing has two vent plugs and two drain connections.
Can I use the second drain connection and build a second trap to install the reverse osmosis system drain?
There is not enough room to install the drain saddle before the trap that comes after the garbage disposal.

Why are there two drain connections?
Drain connections are the two on the right, vents are the two on the left coming from the wall.

I want to build the second trap on the lower drain connection and attach the saddle to this.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I have the same issue!